# NULL values when using overlay_within function in Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, point-in-polygon, within

I have two layers, a point layer and a polygon layer (`'Sektorplan'`). The polygon layer attribute table has a `"Sektor"` column ('1','2', ...).

**The Goal**

I want to add a new column (`"Sector"`) to the attribute table of the point layer to indicate in which sector the point is located.

**Tried so far**

I used `overlay_within('Sektorplan', Sektor)` in the field calculator of the point layer.

**The Problem**

The resulting column only shows `NULL`. Using a Virtual Field or not does not make any difference. The preview of the field calculator shows up correct (['1']).

**Pictures say more than a thousand words**

[image: The table of the polygon layer]

[image: field calculator]

[image: resulting point layer table]

Anyone knows what causes this? My search-fu failed me.

Comment: If you read [the QGIS docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-within), where it says: *"Returns whether the current feature is spatially within at least one feature from a target layer, or an array of expression-based results for the features in the target layer that contain the current feature."*, so using of the [`array_to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-to-string) function additionally is required i.e. `array_to_string(overlay_within('Sektorplan', Sektor))`

Comment: Yes, I overlooked the array part. Thought as there's only one other layer .... It's always those details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`overlay_within` returns `Sektor` value of the related polygon feature(s) as a list/array (even if it returns one polygon). You should convert to string.

Set `Output field type` to `Text` and use this expression:

```
array_to_string(overlay_within('Sektorplan', Sektor))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!
Clearly did not understand that it ALWAYS returns an array.

Comment: It always returns an array since a point may be within multiple polygons., unlike your case.