# PyQGIS: .disjoint() and .equals() do not work

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, overlay, intersect

I have to clean a data set for research. It is just one layer, but I need to remove features that are registered several times or have a geometry that is somehow faulty. The dataset is too large to do this by hand. I wrote a PyQGIS script in QGIS 3.32.2 that takes the input layer, iterates over each feature, creates a bounding box for the current feature and puts the intersecting features from the same layer in a selection. I then iterate over the selection and check for different types of intersection with the current feature. If the feature in the selection is disjoint, I want to transfer them to the resulting memory layer. For transferring to the result layer, I wrote a function called *transfer()*. Likewise, I check if a feature from the selection *equals* the current feature (common issue in the dataset). If it does, it should be deleted since there is one more geometry just like it for it to be able to equal *something*.

Now the issue: actually, I also check for .touches() and .overlaps(), which seems to work fine. However, none of the disjoint features are being transferred and I cannot figure out why not. Also, where there have been overlaying features, the last one that now does not equal anything but itself, is also not transferred to the result layer. It should be since it either is disjoint or touches another layer, which leads to being transferred. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Here is a part of my code:

```
for feature in layer:
#here I create the selection
    for i in selection:
              
        if i.geometry().disjoint(feature.geometry()): #is i from the selection disjoint from the current feature?
            transfer(layer,pr,i) #layer is the input layer, pr the dataProvider of the result and i the feature in the selection

            if i[row_id] not in result_layer_ids: #to not add features twice (i.id() leads to errors in the memory layer)
                result_layer_ids.append(i[row_id])
```

However, this code does not seem to add any disjoint features. I definitely have some in the input dataset. Now to .equals() which continues right under the above code:

```
 if i.geometry().equals(feature.geometry()):
    layer.deleteFeature(i.id()) #as long as something equals something else, one of them has to be deleted
```

Earlier, in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/466752/qgis-overlay-analysis-in-field-calculator/466772?noredirect=1#comment762357_466772) I pre-calculated overlay types and added the result as a string to each feature. However, deleting features, e.g. ones that equal another geometry, changes the result, which would not be reflected in in the pre-calculated value. So, why did disjoint and equals behave as expected in pre-processing, but not in PyQGIS?

Answer (score 0):

I solved both problems in [this final code](https://gist.github.com/TheHelmut/92b05ceec91ddff7a913924b34fb29a1).
The problem with disjoint features was that selecting features based on a bounding box around another feature of the layer means the disjoint feature would have to be intersecting the bounding box, but still disjoint, which is unlikely. Alternating the logic as follows solved that (this happens after creating the selection):

```
    disjoint_from_all = True 
for i in selection:
    if i[row_id] == feature[row_id]: # Skip the feature itself
        continue
    if not i.geometry().disjoint(feature.geometry()): #if only one feature is not disjoint, "flip the swtich"
        disjoint_from_all = False
# After checking against all other features, if it's still disjoint from all:
if disjoint_from_all or len(selection) == 0:# if the feature is disjoint or the feature count intersecting with its bounding box is 0 (another way to express a disjoint here)
    transfer(layer, pr, feature)
    if i[row_id] not in disjoint:
        disjoint.append(i[row_id])
```

Equal features had the issue that all of them were deleted. This was solved by creating an empty set() of Well Known Text (wkt) coordinates. If the wkt-coordinates already were in the set, do nothing. If they weren't add the feature to the result layer:

```
if i.geometry().equals(feature.geometry()):
        #checks if the WKT-geometry already was transferred, works with coordinates instead of ids
        if i.geometry().asWkt() in transferred_geometries:
            continue
        else:
            transfer(layer,pr,i)
```